# Can Open Layer 3 be used as a web component?

Tags: openlayers-3

i'm tasked with attempting to use Open Layer 3 as a web component. I've tried searching online but couldn't come up with any definite Yes or No answer. Does anyone here have an idea? And if it is yes, a clue to some website or book containing the guide would be most helpful. Thank you in advance

Comment: it is hard to answer such question without any idea about your needs and without more concrete details about the challenges you have. Anyway, I found Leaflet more attractive for my needs due to its infinite amount of plugins, and Cesium thanks for the 3D, but that's only from the perspective of the challenges I had.

Comment: Maybe [this tutorial](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/doc/tutorials/closure.html) is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some examples for using OpenLayers 3 as a web component.

Most of them are based on [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org), a library making possible ["to shim"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_%28computing%29) HTML 5 web component features, mainly supported by Google.

The repositories I found so far are :

- https://github.com/fredj/ol3-polymer
- https://github.com/oliverroick/map-components

You should be aware that most of them are far from complete. It's mainly showcases and you will have to extend them depending of your purpose.

PS: For info, the web component world is not developed as it could be. You can see a recent article from [Mozilla Hacks](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/the-state-of-web-components/) about them

Comment: The "map-component" project is more useful for me but unsurprisely it is using an old version of Polymer.  I needed to migrate the ol3-map and ol3-marker components before using them with a more recent version of Polymer ~ v1.7.0

Answer (score 2):

There is now an OpenLayers 5 web component available:

- Starting point: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@openlayers-elements/maps
- GitHub: https://github.com/zazuko/openlayers-elements
- Documentation: https://openlayers-elements.netlify.com/

Full disclosure: This is done by our company